# How to filter MongoDB documents from a list of options (Node.js + Mongoose)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection of products, where each one has an array of properties:

```
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    properties: [{
        name: {type: String, required: true},
        value: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed, required: true},
        unit: {type: String, required: false}
    }]
})
```

I would like to query all the products who's properties match the options I provide

for example, that's the Input:

```
const propertiesToFilter = {
  name: ['intel cpu', 'amd cpu'],
  clockSpeed: [2.6, 3.7],
  generation: [10]
}
```

This would query all the products who's:

- Name is 'intel cpu' or 'amd cpu'
- Clock speed is 2.6 or 3.7
- Generation is 10

I tried something like this:

```
const findObject: any = {}

for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(propertiesToFilter)) {
  findObject['properties.' + key] = {$in: value}
}

const products = await this.productModel.find(findObject).exec()
```

doesn't really work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked Mongoose query constructor docs?
In your case specifically $and and $in?

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query

`{ $and: [{ cpu: { $in: [‘intel’, ‘amd’] }}, { speed: { $in: [2.6, 3.7] }}, { generation: 10 }] }`

Comment: I ended doing that, looping over my properties and "generating" this $and and $in query, it works great now. just one question, is performance should be a concern when i have a large list (100-200) of $and or $in?

Comment: 200 documents is a very small collection, so no.

Comment: Sorry just re read - do you mean you have 100-200 $and statements?

Comment: as my app will scale then yeah, around 200 $and statements